# Is it possible to virtualize multiple sessions of OS using one image?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, remote-access

I've been digging in virtual machines and virtualization in general, so my question is:

Say I have Windows XP image that has multiple users, can I run multiple sessions simultaneously through virtual machines or any other way?

I don't know where to start looking, any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an easy case of creating new virtual *differential* harddrives, using your Windows XP image as a base image. I know this is possible with Virtual PC, and I presume all other virtualization technologies have this. (This is kindof how hyper-v's snapshot process works.)

Note that any change in the base image will invalidate any derived images.

A totally untested idea would be to use Virtual PC's undo disks to avoid persisting anything at all between sessions, but I havnt tested that one with this scenario.